# Recursion - explanation how the code works (drawing)

Tags: java, recursion

i write this code and i try to understand all activities performed (recursive).
Can anyone help me with this draw me up a tree in memory of what happens?

```
public static String row(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return "1";

    else
        return row(n - 1) + " " + n;
}

public static String triangle(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b)
        return row(b);

    else
        return row(a) + "\n" + triangle(a + 1, b);

}
}
```

thank's

Comment: You wrote the code you can't understand?

Comment: As of now, this code creates a string. Tried running the code, and printing the result of that operation?

Comment: A Recursion is a function that calls itself with different input parameters. There also has to be a termination condition so the function doesn't loop endlessly. You should be able to figure out the rest based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `row` method:

```
public static String row(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return "1";
    } else {
        return row(n - 1) + " " + n;
    }
}
```

Returns a String containing all the numbers from 1 - n separated by spaces. E.g.`row(4)` will return a string `"1 2 3 4"`.

Your `triangle` method prints one `row` for each row of a triangle.

```
public static String triangle(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return row(b);
    } else {
        return row(a) + "\n" + triangle(a + 1, b);
    }

}
```

creates one row of a triangle for each step of row from `a` up to `b`.

e.g. `triangle(4,6)` will print:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

### How the code works

The `row` method, if given the value `1` will return "1". Any other value will result in a string equivalent to `row(n-1)` followed by `n` so essentially it will return `1 2 3 ... n`.

The `triangle` method returns a string which attempts to draw a triangle with numbers. Thus `triangle(4,6)` returns `row(4) + triangle(5,6)` which returns `row(5) + triangle(6,6)` which will returns `row(6)`. Thus the final result will be:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
```